# how to find some element has child as div in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

i have a below code.I have tried in several ways by myself..but i can't get it properly.

```
<div id="div1">
<canvas></canvas>
<div>
</div>
</div>
```

i need to do is. that is first i need to check whether the div has child div. and if it has child div then need to add span in that. if it don't have child div means need to add child div and need t add span in that.

```
if($("#div1").has child div)
{
do nothing
}
else{
add div
}
```

In some other instance, i need to add some span in the the inner div..
please help me..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('#div').children().find('div').length)
{
}
else
{
  $('#div').append('<div>Hi</div>');
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, I don't want to use expression "==" especially "something == 0".

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#div1').find('div').length) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the JavaScript code you need:

```
// If no child DIV, add one
if ($("#div1 > div").size() == 0) {
  $("#div1").append('<div></div>');
}

// Append a span to the child DIV
$("#div1 > div").append('<span>This is a span.</span>');
```

---

**DEMO with child DIV:**

```js
if ($("#div1 > div").size() == 0) {
  $("#div1").append('<div></div>');
}

$("#div1 > div").append('<span>This is a span.</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

**DEMO without child DIV:**

```js
if ($("#div1 > div").size() == 0) {
  $("#div1").append('<div></div>');
}

$("#div1 > div").append('<span>This is a span.</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $('#div1').find('div').size() != 0 ) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9vaahd2/1/) try this

```
<div id="div1">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <div></div> <!-- check also after removing this  -->
</div>


(function(){
    var nestDiv = $('#div1').children('div').length;
    if(nestDiv>0){
        $('#div1').children('div').append($('<span></span>',{
            text:'Hello',
            class: 'nestSpan'
        }));
    }else{
        $('#div1').append($('<div><span>hello from double nested</span></div>'));
    }

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

see the code below:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var mainDiv = $('#div1');
    if (mainDiv.find('div').length) {
        mainDiv.find('div').append("<span>").text("dev");
    } else {

        mainDiv.append("<div>").append("<span>").text("dev");
    }
});
```

and i have created a jsfiddle example for you:-
http://jsfiddle.net/c2S5d/11/

you can edit to see the functionality like append the div to it...